# SWT KeyStroke to String

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I am trying to convert a KeyStroke in SWT to a nice user presentation:

```
KeyStroke ks = org.eclipse.jface.bindings.keysKeyStroke.getInstance(SWT.CONTROL + SWT.SHIFT, SWT.F5);
```

which results in

```
CTRL+SHIFT+F5
```

Basically this works, however I have two concerns:

1. When I look at the Eclipse IDE, it shows keyStrokes like this: `Ctrl+Shift+F5`
2. I am wondering why the locale is not considered. I would expect the keyStroke to be `Strg+Shift+F5` on a German locale

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse calls

```java
KeyFormatterFactory.setDefault(SWTKeySupport.getKeyFormatterForPlatform());
```

to set the key formatting to match the normal display for the platform. This may use 'Ctrl+Shift', on my Mac it uses '^⇧'.

This formatter is used by the `KeyStroke.format()` method. If you use the `KeyStroke.toString()` method you always get the upper case version.

Update:
The 'Ctrl'... names are looked up in resource bundle properties files so it should be possible to localize these but the default Eclipse download does not include any localization.